# Use grep for a long line to get the part of the line

Tags: grep

I want to search in a long sentence (more than 1024 letters).

I have one text file (`test.txt`) which has one long sentence, like this:

```
afdafglwqgkjrldjl;ewqje;'k;g;je;;;fdsgalsdkf;akslg;safdas.....dasfsd
```

Now I want to check which line contains the word `saf`. This command just shows the whole sentence:

```
less test.txt | grep saf
```

Is it possible to get a part of the sentence or should I use a command other than `grep`?

Comment: `grep -o 'saf' text.text`?

Comment: THanks! It shows the matched point. however is it possible to show the a few letters before and after of matches???

Comment: `grep -o '.\{0,3\}saf.\{0,3\}' text.text` – this will include up to three characters before and up to three characters after. But if there is a second `saf` and it begins within these "three characters after" then it won't be matched separately.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski It's perfect what I want. it works prety well

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034799/how-to-truncate-long-matching-lines-returned-by-grep-or-ack

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly what you were looking for: show the matching lines and highlight the occurences in those lines:

```
grep --color 'saf' test.txt
```

Options for searching `saf` and displaying up to 15 characters before and after the occurences found using:

- the standard regex syntax, first mentioned by @kamil-maciorowski in his comment on the question:

  ```
  grep -o '.\{0,15\}saf.\{0,15\}' test.txt | grep saf --color
  ```
- Perl-compatible regex syntax with the `-P` option, if available:

  ```
  grep -o -P '.{0,15}saf.{0,15}' test.txt | grep --color saf
  ```
- extended regex syntax with the `-E` option, if your `grep` has no `-P` option (like e.g. on macOS):

  ```
  grep -o -E '.{0,15}saf.{0,15}' test.txt | grep --color saf
  ```

Comment: See my comment under the question. If you add a remark to your answer about a possibility of not matching all `saf`-s, I will upvote it and delete my comment.

Comment: Thanks @t0r0X , I tried your one too . my grep doens't have -P option somehow. and backslash before { is needed. But I appreciate your answer too.

Comment: @whitebear Indeed, not every grep has `-P`, but there's yet another variant, I'll update again my answer.

Comment: @kamil-maciorowski I will look into it.

Comment: This is super useful for grepping on minified files.

Answer (score 0):

**`bgrep` if lines don't necessarily fit into memory**

I keep coming back to this random repo from time to time: https://github.com/tmbinc/bgrep Install:

```
curl -L 'https://github.com/tmbinc/bgrep/raw/master/bgrep.c' | gcc -O2 -x c -o $HOME/.local/bin/bgrep -
```

Use:

```
bgrep `printf %s saf | od -t x1 -An -v | tr -d '\n '` myfile.bin
```

Sample output:

```
myfile.bin: c80000003
\x02abc
myfile.bin: c80000007
dabc
```

I have tested it on files that don't fit into memory, and it worked just fine.

I've given further details at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223078/best-way-to-grep-a-big-binary-file/758528#758528